# django orm group by + distinct

Tags: django, orm, group-by

```
from django.db import models
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    published_years = models.DateField()
    concat = name + author
```

What is the query for get books by 'concat' field, without doublons, and where published_years is the most recent date

Exemple:

```html
<table>
<tr><th>#id</th><th>name</th><th>author</th><th>published_years</th> </tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>nameA</td><td>    author1</td><td>   1996</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>nameA</td><td>    author1</td><td>   1997</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>nameA</td><td>    author2</td><td>   1687</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>nameB</td><td>    author2</td><td>   1987</td></tr>
</table>
=>

<table>
<tr><td>1</td><td>   nameA</td><td>    author1  </td> <td>1997</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>   nameA</td><td>    author2  </td> <td>1687</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>   nameB</td><td>    author2  </td> <td>1987</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `concat` is not a field here, I even think that this might error.

Comment: Furthermore this looks like bad modeling. Typically you want for that case an extra model `BookYear` with a `ForeignKey` to the `Book`, and the model then contains a `year` (or `date`) to specify when it was published.

Comment: There are no way with ORM ?  Maybe something like Books.objects.all().distinct('name','author').order_by('date_years') ?

Comment: there is, but it would only make it harder in the future to make more advanced queries. That is why [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) is so important.

Comment: I have a huge number of data, so it's better if I dont have so many models (table)

Comment: on the contrary: database normalization actually *improves* efficiency when you have huge data, since now, you store an entire row per *published* book, and not per book. This means that if you published a book ten times, that the database will need (approx.) ten times more space than when you used normalization. This will also have a huge impact on performance when retrieving the data, and furthermore it makes it harder/impossible to do proper indexing.

Comment: Denormalized db's are typically *slow*, *bloated*, and *prone to errors*.

Comment: well it should be `published_year` I guess (and furthermore it is a bit odd that it is a `DateField`, what exactly should `published_years` hold? Years, or real dates?

Comment: it's real dates

Answer (score 0):

## Querying with a `QuerySet` of dictionaries

You can make a query like:

```
Book.objects.values('name', 'author').annotate(
    year=Max('published_years')
).order_by('name', 'author')
```

which will result in a `QuerySet` that wraps `dict`ionaries, like:

```
<QuerySet [
    { 'name': 'titleA', 'author': 'authorA', 'year': date(1993, 2, 9)},
    { 'name': 'titleA', 'author': 'authorB', 'year': date(2008, 5, 7)},
    { 'name': 'titleB', 'author': 'authorC', 'year': date(1983, 1, 1)},
    { 'name': 'titleC', 'author': 'authorA', 'year': date(1923, 7, 15)},
]>
```

## Refactoring and annotating

and then you can process these, but as specified in the comments, if the same `name`/`author` contains several duplicates, this means you have an anti-pattern named *data duplication* in your model. You probably should refactor it to:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class BookDate(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    date = models.DateField()
```

Then you can write this as:

```
Book.objects.annotate(
    author_name=F('author__name')
    last_published=Max('bookdate__date')
)
```

which is the a `QuerySet` of `Book`s (so a "richer" construct), and with two extra attributes: `author_name`, and `last_published` already available.